# Parse float from string in regex python with conversion unit

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I am trying to convert all cases below as a float number

See below:

```
['$1.5 million',
 '$2.6 million',
 '$2.28 million',
 '$600,000',
 '$950,000',
 '$858,000',
 '$788,000',
 '$1.35 million',
 '$2.125 million',
 '$1.5 million',
 '$1.5 million',
 '$2.2 million',
 '$1.8 million',
 '$3 million',
 '$4 million',
 '$2 million',
 '$300,000',
 '$1.8 million',
 '$5 million',
 '$4 million',
 '$700,000',
 '$6 million',
 'under $1 million or $1,250,000',
 '$2 million',
 '$2.5 million',
 '$4 million',
 '$3.6 million',
 '$3 million',
 '$3 million',
 '$3 million',
 '$4.4–6 million',
 '$4 million',
 '$5 million',
 '$4 million',
 '$5 million',
 '$8 million',
 'AU$1 million',
 '$5 million',
 '$7.5 million',
 '$10 million',
 '$3.5 to 4 million',
 '$5.25 million',
 '$20 million',
 '$4.5 million',
 '$9 million',
 '$6-8 million',
 '$20 million',
 '$18 million',
 '$12 million',
 '$14 million',
 '$10 million',
 '$17 million',
 '$5 million',
 '$8 million',
 '$20 million',
 '$11 million',
 '$28 million',
 '$44 million',
 '$7.5 million',
 '$14 million',
 '$9 million',
 'A$8.7 million',
 '$31 million',
 '$18 million',
 '$5 million',
 '$40 million',
 '$20 million',
 '$14 million',
 '60 million Norwegian Kroner (around $8.7 million in 1989)',
 '$35-40 million',
 '$25 million',
 '$15 million',
 '$32 million',
 '$14 million',
 '$28 million',
 '$12 million',
 '$11 million',
 '$28 million',
 '$17 million',
 '$30 million',
 '$13 million',
 '$5 million',
 '$45 million',
 '$31 million',
 '$22 million',
 '$30 million',
 '$22 million',
 ['$32 million', '(estimated)'],
 '$18 million',
 '$55 million',
 '$24 million',
 '$15 million',
 '$12 million',
 '$30 million',
 '$31 million',
 '$38 million',
 '$70 million',
 '$15 million',
 '$67 million',
 '$32 million',
 '$7 million',
 '$85 million',
 '$55 million',
 '$3 million',
 '$16 million',
 '$80 million',
 '$30 million',
 '$24 million',
 '$90 million',
 '$15 million',
 '$30 million',
 '$120 million',
 '$90 million',
 '$65 million',
 '$5 million',
 '$130 million',
 '$75–90 million',
 '$10 million',
 '$90 million',
 '$80–85 million',
 '$15 million –$30 million',
 '$4,000,000 (estimated)',
 '$127.5 million',
 '$65 million',
 '$30 million',
 '$85 million',
 '$100 million',
 '$23 million',
 '$90–120 million',
 '$26 million',
 '$25 million',
 '$115 million',
 '$33 million',
 '$20 million',
 '$5 million',
 '$22 million',
 '$80 million',
 '$35 million',
 '$19.2 million',
 '$15 million',
 '$65 million',
 '$140 million',
 '$20 million',
 '$12 million',
 '$46 million',
 '$13 million',
 '$20 million',
 '$17 million',
 '$94 million',
 '$140 million',
 '$26 million',
 '$46 million',
 '$90 million',
 '$10 million',
 '$28 million',
 '$15 million',
 '$110 million',
 '$110 million',
 '$45 million',
 '$92–145 million',
 '$100 million',
 '$20 million',
 '$56 million',
 '$25 million',
 '$50 million',
 ['¥', '2.4 billion', 'US$24 million'],
 '$35 million',
 '$35 million',
 '$25 million',
 '$150 million',
 '$180 million',
 '$30 million',
 '$1 million',
 '$40 million',
 '$50 million',
 '$80 million',
 '$120 million',
 '$225 million',
 '$30 million',
 '$24 million',
 '$8 million',
 '$17 million',
 '$150 million',
 '$300 million',
 '$150 million',
 '$25 million',
 '$22 million',
 '$85 million',
 '$130 million',
 '$7 million',
 '$25 million',
 '$225 million',
 '$180 million',
 '$20 million',
 '$11 million',
 '$50 million',
 '$150 million',
 '$80 million',
 '$50 million',
 '$30 million',
 '$175 million',
 '$150 million',
 ['¥', '3.4 billion', '(', 'US$', '34 million)'],
 '$30—$35 million',
 '$8 million ( ₽ 350 million)',
 '$175–200 million',
 '$35 million',
 '$105 million',
 '$150 –$200 million',
 '$150–200 million',
 '$200 million',
 '$150 million',
 '$22 million',
 '$30—$35 million',
 '$35 million',
 '$260 million',
 '$170 million',
 '$150 million',
 '$8 million',
 ['$410.6 million (gross)', '$378.5 million (net)'],
 '$200 million',
 '$30 million',
 '$45 million',
 '$23 million',
 ['$306.6 million (gross)', '$263.7 million (net)'],
 '$185 million',
 '$25 million',
 '$39 million',
 '$30—35 million',
 '$165 million',
 '$200 million',
 '$200 million',
 '$225–250 million',
 '$50 million',
 '$150 million',
 '$35 million',
 '$25 million',
 '$180–263 million',
 '$50 million',
 '(US$2.9 million)',
 '$28 million',
 '$165 million',
 '$50 million',
 '$17 million',
 '$84.21–95 million',
 '$180–190 million',
 '$175 million',
 '$175–200 million',
 '$70–80 million',
 '$150 million',
 '$175–177 million',
 '$170 million',
 '$200 million',
 '$140 million',
 '$65 million',
 '$15 million',
 '$150–175 million',
 '$160–255 million',
 '$230–320 million',
 '$175 million',
 '131 crore',
 ['~$8 million', '₽', '370 million'],
 '$175–225 million',
 '$100–130 million',
 '$200 million',
 '$65-70 million',
 '$120–133 million',
 '$175 million',
 '$130 million',
 '$170 million',
 '$183 million',
 '$200 million',
 '$250–260 million',
 '$185 million',
 '$60 million',
 '$150 million',
 '$40 million',
 '$42 million',
 '$175–200 million',
 '$125 million',
 '$12.5 million (stage production)',
 '$24 million',
 '$200 million',
 '$26 million',
 '$150 million',
 '₽650 million',
 '$100 million+',
 '$100–200 million',
 '$200 million',
 '$120–150 million',
 '₽454 million',
 '$175 million',
 '$36 million',
 '~$70 million',
 '$200 million',
 '$40 million',
 '$135–180 million',
 '$157.8 million',
 '$175 million',
 '$250–260 million',
 '$53.4 million',
 '$28 million',
 '$858,000',
 '$9 million',
 '$85 million',
 '$70 million',
 '$75–90 million',
 '$80 million',
 '$130 million',
 '$5 million',
 '$18 million or $25 million',
 '$4 million',
 ['$15,000,000', '(1 film)'],
 '$3 million',
 '$11—15 million',
 '$35-40 million',
 '$183 million',
 '$100–200 million',
 '$30 million',
 '$200 million',
 '$200 million',
 ['Total (5 films):', '$1.274–1.364\xa0billion'],
 '$183 million',
 ['Total (5 films):', '$1.274–1.364\xa0billion'],
 '$175–177 million',
 '$150 million',
 '$185 million',
 '$150 million']
```

We have the following cases:

- $1 million
- $300,000
- Ranges of numbers like: $1.5-$2 million (in such case would be ideal to get the average)
- Sometimes we have lists. If we have lists, we just skip them to avoid more overhead.

The following code works pretty well for the first two cases.

For ranges of numbers with "-" does not work and in the following case also fails:
'under $1 million or $1,250,000', --> in this case, I just want to extract the following: 1_250_000 as a float number in Python.

If we have $ vs. other currencies, we just take the number that is after the $-sign.

My attempt:

My regular expression is the following:

```
r"(?=.*mil.*).*\$(?P<value_to_convert>\d*(?:\.\d+)?)\s?(?P<unit>\w+)|.*\$(?P<raw_value>\d+,\d+)"
```

- This takes the positive lookahead to ensure that we have the word "mil"
- It takes any digit followed by an optional decimal and the word which would be a unit of measurement
- The | which takes that or the values that look like this: '$600,000'

```
import re

pattern =  r"(?=.*mil.*).*\$(?P<value_to_convert>\d*(?:\.\d+)?)\s?(?P<unit>\w+)|.*\$(?P<raw_value>\d+,\d+)"

for i in sample:
    match = re.match(pattern, i)
    print(match.groupdict())
```

Any support is appreciated.

Comment: At the very least, the "taking the average of the range" case is impossible with regex only.

Comment: There's a finite number of cases.  Why not just `if-else` them manually?

Comment: The big question is what do you do with the conversion?  I have `$1` and it is 1, now what ? Do I make a new label to track that or is it discarded and the whole thing is an exercise in uselessness ?

Comment: Also, what stops you just cleaning this data?

Comment: if million then we convert it 1 * 1_000_000

Comment: Your list is 1.3 kms. long. Is that necessary?

Comment: How would you convert numbers like `$4.4–6 million` and `under $1 million or $1,250,000`? What about the values that are lists themselves? Break your problem down and try to ask a single question.

Comment: matt, when you address comments that ask for clarification you should edit your question rather than answering in a comment. Questions should be self-contained, in part because not all readers read all comments.

Answer (score 1):

This task is very much harder with regex, here is a solution I just coded for doing what you want:

```
import locale


def milli(item):
    if 'million' in item:
        number = locale.atof(item.replace(' million', '')) * 1000000
        return number


def fetcher(sample):
    for item in sample:
        if '-' in item:
            milli_conv = []
            low_nr = item.split('-')
            for x in low_nr:
                milli_conv.append(milli(x))
            for x in range(len(milli_conv)):
                if milli_conv[x] is None:
                    milli_conv[x] = float(low_nr[0]) * 1000000
            average = (milli_conv[0] + milli_conv[1]) / 2
            print(average)
        elif 'or' in item:
            choices = item.split('or')
            for choice in choices:
                if ',' in choice:
                    strip_any_space = choice.lstrip()
                    strip_dollar = strip_any_space.lstrip('$')
                    number = strip_dollar.replace(',', '')
                    print(float(number))
        elif 'million' in item:
            print(milli(item))
        elif type(item) is not list:
            strip_dollar = item.lstrip('$')
            number = strip_dollar.replace(',', '')
            print(float(number))
```

Call the fetcher function, input your list as parameter, and the results shoud be printed in console

```
fetcher(sample_list)
```